# How to loop for api

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests

print('\033[32m'+"""
*************************************
*                                   *
* @xx                               *
*************************************
"""+'\x1b[0m')

apiKeyim = "7364056d604e5d20156aea759aca32111afe370e"
urlM = "http://pro.viewdns.info"

class viewDns:
    def __init__(self):
        self.api_url = urlM
        self.api_key = apiKeyim

    def revIp(self, domain):
        response = requests.get(f"{self.api_url}/reverseip/?host={domain}&apikey={self.api_key}&output=json")
        return response.json()

vD = viewDns()

while True:
    mSec = input("1- Reverse IP Lookup\n2- Exit\nSelect: ")

    if mSec == "2":
        break
    else:
        if mSec == "1":
            siteList = input("Site Listesi Dosyası : ")

            listemiz = open(siteList, "r")
            sitever = listemiz.read()
            listemiz.close()
            for i in sitever.split("\n"):
                domain = str(i)
            dom = vD.revIp(domain)
            try:
                for d in dom["response"]["domains"]:
                    dosya = open(domain+"_revIp.txt", "a", encoding='utf-8')
                    dosya.write(d['name']+'\n')
                    dosya.close()
                print("\033[91m\033[1mSaved to file : "+domain+"_revIp.txt\x1b[0m")
            except KeyError:
                print("\033[91m\033[1mDomain not detected.!\x1b[0m")
        else:
            print("\033[91m\033[1mIncorrect Selection.\x1b[0m".center(50,'*'))
```

I get the error "Domain not detected.!" and it doesn't work as I want,

I want it to do "Reverse Lookup" for each of the domains in the txt, and it needs to export the result as a txt.

Since it can scan a single domain with the api, I need to loop it for each line in the txt

Comment: something probably wemt wrong when in rev(); are you sure that the f-string url is correct?

Comment: apiKeyim = "7364056d604e5d20156aea759aca32111afe370e" shouldn't be kept secret ?

Comment: http ://pro.viewdns.info ----> https ://pro.viewdns.info ??

Comment: The apikey has expired and is not a problem

Comment: indentation here: for i in sitever.split("\n"):
                domain = str(i)
            dom = vD.revIp(domain)
            try:
                for d in dom["response"]["domains"]:
                    dosya = open(dom

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests

print('\033[32m'+"""
*************************************
*                                   *
* @xx                               *
*************************************
"""+'\x1b[0m')

apiKeyim = "7364056d604e5d20156aea759aca32111afe370e"
urlM = "https://pro.viewdns.info"

class viewDns:
    def __init__(self):
        self.api_url = urlM
        self.api_key = apiKeyim

    def revIp(self, domain):
        response = requests.get(f"{self.api_url}/reverseip/?host={domain}&apikey={self.api_key}&output=json")
        return response.json()

vD = viewDns()

while True:
    mSec = input("1- Reverse IP Lookup\n2- Exit\nSelect: ")

    if mSec == "2":
        break
    else:
        if mSec == "1":
            siteList = input("Site Listesi Dosyası : ")

            listemiz = open(siteList, "r")
            sitever = listemiz.read()
            listemiz.close()
            for i in sitever.split("\n"):
                domain = str(i)
                dom = vD.revIp(domain)
                try:
                  for d in dom["response"]["domains"]:
                    dosya = open(domain+"_revIp.txt", "a", encoding='utf-8')
                    dosya.write(d['name']+'\n')
                    dosya.close()
                    print("\033[91m\033[1mSaved to file : "+domain+"_revIp.txt\x1b[0m")
                 except KeyError:
                    print("\033[91m\033[1mDomain not detected.!\x1b[0m")
         else:
                     print("\033[91m\033[1mIncorrect Selection.\x1b[0m".center(50,'*'))
```

Comment: I could not understand where you made changes in the code

Comment: indentation, now the file are identical, tomerikoo edited your question (I believe)  you can use https://meldmerge.org/ to compare file or diff https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/diff-command-linux-examples/

Comment: I've checked with diff before, can't see any change and also has alignment problem

Comment: from here:             dom = vD.revIp(domain)

Comment: same as the previous one

Comment: cant connect to the server. Hope someone better will help you. the examples here should be reproducible so that anybody could run your code and debug  it

Comment: Have you checked the server response ??